# What is subcomponents in awt and can you retrieve all of them?

Tags: java, awt

In the java docs for `java.awt.Component` the method `getComponentAt` describes that it can return a component or a subcomponent.

What is a subcomponent?
Is there a way to retrieve all subcomponents from a component?

Subcomponent mentioned here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html

Comment: It's a component held by another component. You can get all components/subcomponents by writing a recursive method that calls getComponents[]. question: why AWT and not Swing?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels You can't call getComponents on a Component, right? I'm using AWT because I am making a client for a online applet, which is using AWT. I don't have access to the code of the applet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

awt uses `Container` as a special class of `Component` which can contain other components. So the enumeration of all components is called `Container.getComponents()`. Why they decided to have the subcomponent access in the `Component` class instead of the `Container` class, I don't know, but that's the way it is. Perhaps the reason is that `getComponentAt` will also return the component for which the method was invoked, if there is no sub-component in that location, and if it actually contains the given position.

So to find all subcompnents, check whether the component is a container. If it is not, then it cannot have subcomponents. If it is, then cast to `Container` and access them. Recurse if you need sub-sub-components as well.